# How to convert an opencv mat image to gdi bitmap

Tags: c++, opencv, bitmap, gdi+

I want to convert an openCV Mat file into a GDI+ BitMap image. I cannot find any information on how to do this?

I think there is no straight way of doing this, but I hope that it is not involved of writing it to a file and reading back (http://opencv-users.1802565.n2.nabble.com/Convert-IplImage-to-Bitmap-td3784378.html )

I need to write something such as this:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <gdiplus.h>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace Gdiplus;

Bitmap GetBitMap(cv::Mat inputImage)
{
   Bitmap bitmap;
   // convert inputImage to bitmap??
   return bitmap;
}
```

Comment: Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe the specific problem — and include valid code to reproduce it — in the question itself. See SSCCE.org for guidance.

Comment: @JohnDibling: Added some sample code. Hope it explain what I am trying to do.

Comment: I wrote a class CGdiPlus that does exactly what you need:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24725155/opencv-tesseract-how-to-replace-libpng-libtiff-etc-with-gdi-bitmap-load-in

Comment: I wrote a class that does exactly what you want:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24725155/opencv-tesseract-how-to-replace-libpng-libtiff-etc-with-gdi-bitmap-load-in

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms536315%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), it appears that `Bitmap` has a constructor taking a pre-allocated memory buffer. Using this constructor, your function might look like this:

```
Bitmap GetBitMap(cv::Mat inputImage)
{
    cv::Size size = inputImage.size();
    Bitmap bitmap(size.width, size.height, inputImage.step1(), PixelFormat24bppRGB, inputImage.data);
    return bitmap;
}
```

Be advised that the `Bitmap` returned from your function does not manage the memory you initialize it with. Thus, make sure the image data is being kept alive for the lifetime of the `Bitmap`.

Comment: I am not sure that it works when OpenCv image is not continues?

Comment: @mans what do mean by the bitmap being continuous? can you please explain